# Update detailTextLabel outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, reloaddata, detailtextlabel

I'm using dynamic cells with reusable prototypes and have always set up the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

For one of the cells I'd like to update the detail text label numerous times (a test is being run, and I want to update the user as each stage occurs).

Is this possible to do?

I tried this:

The detaillabel is currently set to the value of "statusText", which is blank to start with. My idea was to use a delegate, pass the string to it and then reload the tabledata, but this isn't working.

Currently I have:

Code when a status changes:

```
[self currentStatus:@"Speed Test Initialized"];
```

currentStatus method:

```
- (void) currentStatus:(NSString *)status {

    [statusDelegate currentStatus:status];
    statusText = status;
    NSLog(@"Current status: %@", statusText);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Now that statusText equals a value I wanted the cell to update upon reload, but it doesn't.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified this and also needed to re-connect my tableview as an IB outlet! That solved the issue.